# Externally Control Application (Interface)

Tags: macos, audio, gui

There is an application that I use as a mixer. It has a gui which looks like a mixer- some knobs and some faders, etc. If you don't know what I mean here is an example:

[image: example mixer gui]

A consistent issue I face is having no ability to control parameters in this application from an external source: either another application, or an external hardware device. Usually I would do this via `OSC` or `Midi` over an internal midi bus, but that's not an option.

A past solution I have used is writing a python script that listens on a midi bus and then launches an automator script which hi-jacks the mouse and makes clicks on the window. That was ***okay*** for a boolean option (e.g. clicking a Mute toggle button). But it doesn't work for parameters that store a value like a volume slider.

Does anyone have any suggestions / creative solutions for controlling application parameters that are only (*or only seem to be*) accessible through the app's interface?

Comment: I too interested

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the devices are on the same network, as I can't ask in a comment. So I'll risk it and suggest a utility for OSX:

[KeyboardMaestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com)

It can record mouse clicks and drags and keystrokes, and the drags can be relative to certain windows rather than direct pixel locations. That way the window can move and the macros will still work.

It also has a companion iOS app that can trigger the recorded mouse drags and keystrokes.